# AppleScript Set zoom level in safari

Tags: safari, applescript, zooming

Did you have any idea how to setup a default zoom in safari for a specific windows (not using keystroke)

Here is my script missing the zoom option

tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    set URL of document 1 to "https://URL"
    set bounds of window 1 to {24, 96, 524, 396}

end tell